# How can I make a list out of the values of an input?

Tags: python, list

This is quite a simple task but I'm not sure how to do it correctly and efficiently.

What I want is the user to enter some strings and to convert those str into values of a list

**Example:**

input:

```
"Banana Apple Car dog"
```

output:

```
["Banana", "Apple", "Car", "dog"]
```

Comment: Use split to convert to a list of strings

Comment: What does "the values of an input" mean? How do you know, for example, that the desired output is *not* ['B', 'a', 'n', ... etc.?

Comment: When asking this sort of question ,it's important to show what you've already tried based on your own research